# Force "TOP 100 PERCENT" in EF "sub-query" queryable

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

**Update:** I was *mistaken* about `top 100 percent` generating a better query plan (the plan is still much better for a reasonably sized `top N`, and probably has to do with parameter sniffing).

While I still think this focused question has merit, it is not "a useful solution" for my problem<sup>2</sup>, and might not be for yours ..

---

I am running into some queries which SQL Server optimizes poorly. The statistics appear correct, and SQL Server chooses the 'worse' plan that performs a seek over *millions* of records even though the estimated and actual values are the same - but this question is *not* about that<sup>1</sup>.

In the problematic queries are of the simplified form:

```sql
select * from x
join y on ..
join z on ..
where z.q = ..
```

However (and since I know the cardinalities better, apparently) the following form consistently results in a *much* better query plan:

```sql
select * from x
join (
  -- the result set here is 'quite small'
  select top 100 percent *
  from y on ..
  join z on ..
  where z.q = ..) t on ..
```

In L2S the `Take` function can be used to limit to `top N`, but the "problem" I have with this approach is that requires a finite/fixed N such that some query could hypothetically just break, instead of just running really slow with the forced materialization.

While I could choose a 'very large' value for the `top N` this, ironically (wrt to the initial problem), increases the SQL query execution time as the value of N increases. The expected intermediate result is only expected to be a few dozen to a few hundred records. The current code I have runs a `top 100` and then, if such was detected to contain too many results, runs the query again without the limit: but this feels like a kludge .. on top of a kludge.

The question is then: can a EF/L2E/LINQ query generate the equivalent of a `top 100 percent` on an *EF Queryable*?

(Forcing materialization via ToList is not an option because the result should be an *EF Queryable* and remain in LINQ to Entities, not LINQ to Objects.)

While I am currently dealing with EF4, if this is [only] possible in a later version of EF I *would* accept such as an answer - such is useful knowledge and does answer the question asked.

---

<sup>1</sup> If wishing to answer with "don't do that" or an "alternative", please make it is an secondary answer or aside *along* with an answer to the actual question being asked. Otherwise, feel free to use the comments.

---

<sup>2</sup> In addition to `top 100 percent` not generating a better query plan, I forgot to include the 'core issue' at stake, which is bad parameter sniffing (instance is SQL Server 2005).

The following query takes a very long to to complete while direct variable substitution runs "in the blink of an eye" indicating an issue with the parameter sniffing.

```sql
declare @x int
set @x = 19348659

select
op.*
from OrderElement oe
join OrderRatePlan rp on oe.OrdersElementID = rp.OrdersElementID
join OrderPrice op on rp.OrdersRatePlanID = op.OrdersRatePlanID
where oe.OrdersProductID = @x
```

The kludged-but-workable query

```sql
select
  op.*
from OrderPrice op
join (
  -- Choosing a 'small value of N' runs fast and it slows down as the
  -- value of N is increases where N >> 1000 simply "takes too long".
  -- Using TOP 100 PERCENT also "takes too long".
  select top 100
    rp.*
  from OrderElement oe
  join OrderRatePlan rp on oe.OrdersElementID = rp.OrdersElementID
  where oe.OrdersProductID = @x
) rp
on rp.OrdersRatePlanID = op.OrdersRatePlanID
```

Comment: Can't you pass a `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: @xanatos Yes, although I've added a bit in the question about using such a strategy.

Comment: Why do you need TOP 100 PERCENT? Is the query plan different if you don't use it? (so if you do the second query without the TOP)?

Comment: I don't think you can make EF generate such SQL, I never saw it containing anything similar.

Comment: And I think this is sort of XY problem. Instead of looking how to do it, reevaluate the need for it, find another way to improve the execution plan.

Comment: @xanatos Oh, my mistake. `TOP 100 PERCENT` is no better than the original query plan..

Comment: @xanatos I've updated the question .. for posterity at this point.

Comment: @abatishchev I think a general consensus for that is "don't use EF" :< There are *many* questions relating to EF and parameter-related issues.

Comment: I'd say maybe "don't use EF _here_", indeed there are various corner and performance cases where EF doesn't work well enough.

Comment: Try to run the same EF/C# code against SQL Server 2012 or 2014. Maybe it's an issue of 2005. It's _really_ old version. It's even not 2008 R2 which is already pretty old too.

Comment: @abatishchev Oh, I *wish* the SQL Servers were updated (it's a mixed farm and 'eventually' these databases will be migrated)! Transaction support is so much better these days .. but business is business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do your own query.

```
db.SqlQuery<something>("SELECT * FROM x ...");
```

Comment: As a side note, I've never found any circumstance in which what you are claiming to optimize the query actually does so if everything else is correct (statistics, etc).  In the few cases I've found where it might help it is because a DBA who "knew better" did something bad.  I'd take a look at the query that LINQ generates as trying to optimize a LINQ query with the assumption that it is going to generate it the way you have laid out is probably incorrect and a waste of trying to optimize something that will never actually happen.

Comment: (I don't mind a relevant aside in the answer, where it will be more visible - just make sure it doesn't take "the" answer! I often add a `---` region at the bottom.)

Comment: It appears to be related to parameter sniffing (which does not appear to be generally avoidable in EF) .. can replicate in SSMS only when using a variable. In any case, this does appear to answer my question - as misguided as it may be.

Comment: Ah yes, I do seem to recall that issue at one point, but it wasn't something that happened with all queries.  And if I recall, it was also on SQL Server 2005 and then only when inside a stored procedure.